# How can we decide a glue or a kern when we are writing a macro?

Tags: plain-tex

I don't know if I am right. Let's read the codes :)

```
\setbox0=\vbox{a\par
  \vskip2pt
  \kern2pt
  b}
\showbox0
```

the snippet of the log file:

```
.\glue 2.0
.\kern 2.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
.\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
```

When we

```
\setbox1=\vbox{\unvbox0
  \setbox2=\lastbox
  \unskip
  \unskip
  \global\skip0=\lastkern
  \unkern
  \global\skip1=\lastskip
  \unskip}
```

Sometimes, we have no chance of examining the log file, so, how can we decide the glue or the kern in some `\skip<number>` is glue or kern?

Comment: You can use e-TeX's `\lastnodetype` (`texdoc etex` is your friend).

Comment: @egreg thank you, egreg, I will visit my friend :)

Comment: @egreg: I notice that when I input etex in the shell, it refers to pdfTeX.

Comment: Yes: the modern TeX distributions always use `pdftex` for `etex`, `pdftex`, `latex` and `pdflatex`.

Comment: BTW, use odd numbers for local assignments and even numbers for global assignments of the first ten scratch registers (`\global\skip1=\lastkern` and `\global\skip3=\lastskip`). This is the convention in plain TeX and LaTeX to prevent problems with "save stack buildup".

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I will follow your useful and important advice. When reading the TeX codes, I have noticed the difference but don't know why. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with e-TeX (which is incorporated in `pdftex`):

```
\def\unkernorunskip#1{%
  \ifnum\lastnodetype=12 % kern
    \global\skip#1=\lastkern\unkern
  \else
    \ifnum\lastnodetype=11 % skip
      \global\skip#1=\lastskip\unskip
    \fi
  \fi}


\setbox0=\vbox{a\par
  \vskip4pt
  \kern2pt
  b}

\setbox1=\vbox{\unvbox0
  \setbox2=\lastbox
  \unskip
  \unskip
  \unkernorunskip{1}%
  \unkernorunskip{3}%
  }

\showthe\skip1
\showthe\skip3
```

The output is

```
> 2.0pt.
l.24 \showthe\skip1

?
> 4.0pt.
l.25 \showthe\skip3

?
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I can always ask a teacher like you when in troube.

Comment: @TimLi You have asked eight questions, of which six received at least an answer. Please review them and, if one of the answers has helped you, mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark next to the vote marks. This is useful for future readers, who can thus know what answer helped you most.

Comment: Yeah, I have done that :)

Comment: @TimLi Upvoting is not the same as accepting.

Comment: This time, I really have marked all :)

Answer (score 5):

In classic TeX you can not tell. You can examine `\lastskip` or `\lastkern` but these will be 0pt whether the last item on the list is not a skip or if it is a skip of size 0pt, you can not distinguish those cases.

Using e-tex however you can examine the value of the integer `\lastnodetype` which will be 11 for a glue (skip) node and 12 for a kern node.