# Horizontal spacing commands

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

What is the difference between math mode horizontal spacing and text mode horizontal spacing?

Actually, I want to understand, why are few commands used in math mode only (say   : and \;) while commands like \quad , \qquad are used in math mode as well as in text mode?

Comment: See: [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/124842)

Answer (score 8):

Spacing commands for text mode can also be used in math mode, but not conversely, unless you load `amsmath` (for a couple of them).

The LaTeX kernel defines `\,` `\:` and `\;` for `\mskip\thinmuskip`, `\mskip\medmuskip` and `\mskip\thickmuskip` respectively. For reference

- `\,` is the space between an ordinary symbol and an operator or conversely (like in `2\sin x`) or after a punctuation symbol;
- `\:` is the space around a binary operation symbol (like in `a+b`);
- `\;` is the space around a relation symbol (like in `a>b`).

However, the LaTeX kernel defines `\,` to be also used in text mode, inserting a *kern* of width 0.1667em (3/18-th of an em). If `amsmath` is loaded, also `\:` and `\;` can be used in text mode, inserting kerns of 0.2222em (4/18-th of an em) and 0.2777em (5/18-th of an em). These width are the same natural widths of the math mode spacings, expressed in `em` units (but the em can differ).

Specific math mode spacing indeed uses `mu` units, where 18mu is the same as 1em in the math symbol font. Such units can only be used as arguments to `\mskip` or `\mkern`, which is legal only in math mode. On the other hand, standard units and `\hskip` or `\kern` can appear in math mode as well as in text mode (and `em` will refer to the font current when math mode was started).

This explains why `\quad` and `\qquad` can be used in math mode: they will add 1em of space referring to the current text font. In some *rare* occasions `\hspace` can turn out to be useful (notice the emphasis, though).

### Further readings

[What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing)

[Lengths and when to use them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them)

[Difference between \mskip and \mkern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112287/difference-between-mskip-and-mkern)

[How can we decide a glue or a kern when we are writing a macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106193/how-can-we-decide-a-glue-or-a-kern-when-we-are-writing-a-macro)